# Finding a Specific Element Inside Other Formulas

Tags: excel, string, function, excel-formula, words

I need help writing a function to find "**Th+4**" and ignore all other attached chemical elements.

Example of the data;

```
/HASr+(aq)  1.2595E-12
Sr+2    2.9449E-06
SrCl+   1.4637E-10
SrCO3 (aq)  1.01E-10
SrF+    2.1778E-11
SrHCO3+ 3.2969E-09
```

How can I find only **Sr+2** and ignore all the others? For now, I was using this function to find it, but it displays all elements containing **Sr2+**.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Sr+2",A7,1)),B7,"")
```

Please help, 
Thank you !

Comment: Why did your question start out asking about `Th+4` then now you want `Sr+2`?

Comment: Also, please clarify your question on the **expected** outcome. So what happens when you "find" this? Do you want to return the column's value to the right of what you find?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very vague, but I assume that when you "locate" your value, you want to return the value to the right.

You can use `Index()` and `Match()` to do this for you.

Assuming that your lookup range is column A, and the value to return is column B, this should work:

```
=INDEX(A:B,MATCH("Sr+2", A:A),2)
```

[image]

> ### Breaking Down the Formula
>
> **Index()**
>     - `A:B` is the entire range to index. Your lookup value is column **A**, and your return value is column **B**
>     - `Match()` is returning the row number, which we will show that below.
>     - `2` is column to cross reference the return value of the row from `Match()`. Since `Match()` gives us the row #, this gives us the column number to "pin-point" the return value
>
> ---
>
> **Match()**
>    - `"Sr+2"` is the string to be searched for
>    - `A:A` is the location to search for this string.
>   *This returns the row to your `Index()` function*

Comment: Hi, thank you all for the answers! I agree my explanation was vague and not to the point. I figured out how it works :)! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

An alternate method from using `Index()` & `Match()` is to use `VLOOKUP()`. This function essentially combines the two previous functions for the same purpose in your case.

```
=VLOOKUP("Sr+2",A:B,2)
```

[image]

> ### [Using the `VLOOKUP()` Function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1)
>
> Use **VLOOKUP**, one of the lookup and reference functions, when you need to find things in a table or a range by row. For example, look up a price of an automotive part by the part number.
>
> In its simplest form, the **VLOOKUP** function says:
> *=VLOOKUP(Value you want to look up, range where you want to lookup the value, the column number in the range containing the return value, Exact Match or Approximate Match – indicated as 0/FALSE or 1/TRUE).*

Answer (score 1):

I also found that this works for my problem;

```
=IF((EXACT($AG$38,A7)),B7,"")
```

Thank you for all your answers :)!

Have a great day!